# Associate a label to MVC RadioButtonFor element

Tags: asp.net-mvc, radio-button

Hi fairly new to using MVC radio buttons. I have some code:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => item.CheckerApproved, true)
<label for="?">Accepted</label>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => item.CheckerApproved, false)
<label for="?">Rejected</label>
```

As you can see I'm not sure how to associate the label with the radiobutton.

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `LabelFor` helper.

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.CheckerApproved)
```

Comment: This does not work as it's rendered as follows:


 `<div class="editor-field">
  <input checked="checked" id="CheckerApproved" name="CheckerApproved" type="radio" value="False">
  <label for="CheckerApproved">CheckerApproved</label>
  <input id="CheckerApproved" name="CheckerApproved" type="radio" value="True">
  <label for="CheckerApproved">CheckerApproved</label>
 </div>`

=> note the id duplication

Comment: @janv8000 what version of mvc are you using?